# AssertionError: Expected 201 instead of 400

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js, chai

I am testing for a post API endpoint and getting the error message above. 
I have searched for related problems on google but could not find one that helps.

```
describe('POST /api/v1/orders', () => {
  it('should add new orders', (done) => {
    chai.request(server)
      .post('/api/v1/orders')
      .send({
        name: 'Tope',
        date: new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '-'),
        designation: 'Oshodi',
        dishType: 'Amala',
        drink: 'Goldspot',
        qty: 2,
        price: 2340,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        res.should.to.have.status(201);
        res.body.should.have.property('result');
        res.body.should.be.an('object');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    done();
  });
});
```

Comment: First thing to do: Check the server logs.

Comment: You should put the `done();` inside `then()` and `catch()`

Comment: No error in the server log. After changing the done(); position. The error remains.